# Python selenium execute_script ajax request not returning response

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, selenium

I want to execute a ajax request onto a site but when I run the code, it prints out "None" and not the result.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://google.com"
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get(url)
r = d.execute_script("""
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://google.com',
    type: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
        //header
    },
    success: function(result) {
        return result;
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
        return jqXHR.status;
    }
});
""")
print(r)
```

Is there a way to make it so that it waits for the ajax reponse before moving on and printing out r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Used the *`execute_async_script`* function instead of the *`execute_script`* function and the reponse came through.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried researching on how to use `WebDriverWait`?

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

If you can identify an element when Ajax responds you can do a command like this:

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Source: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

(Thanks to the guy who posted before on my thread that helped me find a solution similar to yours)